# MSAL Android ADFS support

Tags: android, adfs, azure-ad-msal

i have an android app running msal 2.2.2 and have been connecting to azure ad perfectly.
I now have a need to get it to connect to ADFS 2019
Does this library support it and if so how do i format the .json for it? ive seen some people talk about msal and adfs but i cant find any example of how to format the .json file they talk about here for adfs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-configuration)

Ive been given

Client ID: ???????
Client Secret: ?????
Metadata: https://f????

URLS configured:
https://???
https://?????

Application identifier:
???? (this seems to be the same as Client ID is this right?

Can anyone help me please?

Many thanks

Trev

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of MSAL [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/msal/adfs-msal-web-app-web-api) available for ADFS 2019.

Look at the menu on the left hand side for more.

Yes, ADFS 2019 supports MSAL but no earlier versions do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i was just wondering what the .json file format had to be for MSAL for Android as the examples do talk about ADFS for web but nothing for Android so i want sure how to format the .json file.

Comment: ive just tried a json file like below, once entering the username, it takes me to their system to enter the password, when i do this i get the message. Application with the identifier '???' was not found in the directory '???' t
 "client_id" : "?????",
 "client_secret" : "??????",
 "authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT",
 "redirect_uri" : "msauth://??????",
 "account_mode" : "SINGLE",    
 "broker_redirect_uri_registered": true,
 "shared_device_mode_supported": true,
 "authorities" : [
    {
     "type": "AAD"
    }
   ]
}